# How i can fix zsh: permission denied: /etc/hosts?

Tags: laravel

I try to configure virtual host with code:

```
 echo 127.0.0.1 laravel-app.test >> /etc/hosts
```

but i have a problem "zsh: permission denied: /etc/hosts"

Can you help me to fix my problem?

Comment: Try `sudo echo 127.0.0.1 laravel-app.test >> /etc/hosts  `

Comment: I have done that, but zsh: permission denied: /etc/hosts

Comment: are you _sure_ you added `sudo`?

Answer (score 2):

For your specific use:

```
sudo sh -c "echo '127.0.0.1 laravel-app.test' >> /etc/hosts"
```

This also works for more complex heredoc cases:

```
sudo sh -c "cat << EOF >> /etc/hosts

#### added for development
127.0.0.1  laravel-app.test
127.0.0.1  oid-provider.test
####
EOF"
```

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/769986/bash-etc-hosts-permission-denied